# iOS Getting NSRangeException crash when search online database

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm getting an **occasional crash** when I try and search some text using `UISearchBar`/`searchDisplayController`. I'm searching data from an online database via **JSON** and everything works flawlessly 99% of the time. I'm using the `textDidChange` delegate method to search as the user types in his search.

Here is an example of crashes I am getting:

```
Fatal Exception: NSRangeException 
-[__NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (2) beyond bounds (2)
```

or

```
Fatal Exception: NSRangeException 
*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 6 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]
```

It's really hard for me to nail down what is giving me the crash because when I try and recreate what caused the crash, I can't. The app will work fine for days and tons of "testing" (e.g. me entering queries over and over). Then randomly will crash, then nothing for days.

Here are some the delegate methods that update my `TableViews`.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return [[SearchInfo sharedInfo].searchArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

////////Adds search data to local Array to pass it around the applicatio//////
searchData = [[SearchInfo sharedInfo].searchArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

//Standard Table View Cell
UITableViewCell *searchCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if (searchCell==nil) {

searchCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}


///////////Search bar tableview//////////
if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
searchCell.textLabel.text = [SearchData objectForKey:@"title"];
searchCell.detailTextLabel.text = [SearchData objectForKey:@"system_title"];
}

///////Builds the custom tableview cell//////
UILabel *searchTitleLabel = (UILabel*)[searchCell viewWithTag:1];
searchTitleLabel.text = [searchData objectForKey:@"title"];
UILabel *systemTitleLabel = (UILabel *)[searchCell viewWithTag:2];
systemTitleLabel.text = [searchData objectForKey:@"system_title"];
UILabel *devLabel = (UILabel*)[searchDataCell viewWithTag:3];

if([[searchData objectForKey:@"developer"] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])

{
if([[searchData objectForKey:@"developer"] isEqualToString:@""] || [[searchData objectForKey:@"developer"] isEqualToString:@"<null>"])
{
developerLabel.text = @"Unknown";
}
else {
developerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[searchData objectForKey:@"developer"]];
}

}
else {
developerLabel.text = @"Unknown";
}



////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
return searchCell;
}
```

If you need anything else, let me know! I'm pulling my hair out over here.

Here is the crash log:

```
Thread : Fatal Exception: NSRangeException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x2577cc1f __exceptionPreprocess + 126
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x32f27c8b objc_exception_throw + 38
2  CoreFoundation                 0x25691a8d CFRunLoopRemoveTimer
3  Archive.vg                     0x00073ddb -[CenterViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] (CenterViewController.m:192)
4  UIKit                          0x28f018c7 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 474
5  UIKit                          0x28f0198b -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:] + 54
6  UIKit                          0x28ef70e1 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 2268
7  UIKit                          0x28d0f2ff -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 186
8  UIKit                          0x28c394d7 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 514
9  QuartzCore                     0x28661a0d -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 136
10 QuartzCore                     0x2865d3e5 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 360
11 QuartzCore                     0x2865d26d CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 16
12 QuartzCore                     0x2865cc51 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 224
13 QuartzCore                     0x2865ca55 CA::Transaction::commit() + 324
14 QuartzCore                     0x2865692d CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 56
15 CoreFoundation                 0x257433b5 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
16 CoreFoundation                 0x25740a73 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 278
17 CoreFoundation                 0x25740e7b __CFRunLoopRun + 914
18 CoreFoundation                 0x2568f211 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 476
19 CoreFoundation                 0x2568f023 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
20 GraphicsServices               0x2ca880a9 GSEventRunModal + 136
21 UIKit                          0x28c9b1d1 UIApplicationMain + 1440
22 Archive.vg                     0x0009d0cd main (main.m:16)
23 libdyld.dylib                  0x334a7aaf start + 2
```

Comment: Never mind all that code. Just show the code _where the crash occurs_, please.

Comment: `[SearchInfo sharedInfo].searchArray` is clearly changing. You should lock it down so that it doesn't change between calls to `numberOfRowsInSection:` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: @matt I added a crash log. It crashes with a SIGABRT. I'll add an Exception Breakpoint when I get home.

Comment: @IanMacDonald You're right, that changes as the user enters text. Is that the source of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

you can set breakpoint for exception. It really helpful on debug

you can enable it on menu Debug->Breakpoints->Create Exception Breakpoint

next time you hit exception you will see where it come from.

**Added:**

`@synchronized([SearchInfo sharedInfo].searchArray)
{ 
    ... update table here ... 
}`

Comment: When you hit the breakpoint you can see where you are but not the error messages until you continue (Control-Command-Y) twice. The breakpoint is before the error message printing.

Comment: try to lock or @synchronize [SearchInfo sharedInfo].searchArray to prevent changing it while table updates itself ?

Comment: @ekiyanov Is that as simple as @synchronized(self) {  [SearchInfo sharedInfo].searchArray } ?

Comment: `@synchronized([SearchInfo sharedInfo].searchArray){ ... update table here ... } `

Comment: can't understand how this fix can work : if everything is executed on the main thread and tableview updates are performed for each change, the synchronization shouldn't change anything. I may be wrong but I would like to figure out why as I have the same crash...

Answer (score 0):

> You're right, that changes as the user enters text. Is that the source of the problem?

Yes. You will need to keep your data consistent while your table is loading. If you want to be lazy about it, simply do a `indexPath.row < [[SearchInfo sharedInfo].searchArray count]` check and return an empty cell. It's not the best solution. Realistically, you shouldn't be changing your data so often; if you do change your data a lot, create a new `UITableView` for each data set and assign their data sources statically to ensure they load data independently.

Comment: Alright, I'll give that a shot when I get home. Thanks!